# Recover delted file that Recuva cannot recover

Tags: windows, ubuntu, data-recovery

I have accidentally deleted a file, which I want to recover now.

I had Recuva already installed on my system, and it instantly found the file.
However, it couldn't recover the file (didn't say it was corrupted or similar) and there was no constructive error message, just that the recovery failed.

Beforehand, the file was protected, which made copying and working with the file difficult, because programs didn't have enough rights to do anything with it. (I think this is the reason why it couldn't recover it.

I didn't want to install another data recovery software, because I didn't want to risk overwriting the file.

So I installed Ubuntu onto an USB Stick and booted the PC from there.
However, all data recovery programs I tried either don't work or don't show the deleted file.

I know the exact path and size of the file, but that doesn't help me in any way.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: what specifically do you mean by "...the file was Protected...". do you mean it was encrypted? what other data recovery programs did you use specifically? path is largely meaningless with deleted data, since the path is just file system metadata, and you deleted the file by removing that very same metadata. thats the basic premise upon which data recovery is based; that the file still exists as raw data somewhere on your disk but that the metadata that tells us there is a file in a particular block, with a particular name and path no longer exists